# How can I scroll aside (the sidebar) of a web page using selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using selenium webdriver to parse through news agency. But I need to scroll down but not in body, in the sidebar to get all the news. How can I scroll down through sidebar in Selenium. I am using python.

Comment: Can you please share the url if it's public?

Comment: Yes, of couse, but it is in Russian, i hope it would not be problem. So, i want to take hrefs from sidebar(which is on the left), but this sidebar can be scrolled and new and new hrefs apears. I want to scroll it to the end, and parse all hrefs. If you have other ideas how to do this, I will be grateful. https://www.vedomosti.ru/archive/2010/03/23